# Running binaries inside docker

Tags: docker

Is it possible to use Docker like a VM and run binaries in it? I have an ELF binary to debug/reverse engineer but I'm on a Mac so I can't run it. I've tried mounting it through a shared volume with `docker run -it -v ~/Projects:/Projects ubuntu` and `chmod +x` but it tells me no such file or directory when I tried to execute it.

So starting a docker instance seems fine, it drops me into a root shell.

```
$ docker run -it -v ~/Projects:/Projects ubuntu /bin/bash]
root@21aee00b6c45:/# cd Projects/
root@21aee00b6c45:/Projects#
```

Then I attempt to run my binary which gives me

```
root@21aee00b6c45:/Projects# ls -la ch25.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12751 Apr 28 09:16 ch25.bin
root@21aee00b6c45:/Projects# ./ch25.bin
bash: ./ch25.bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `docker run -it -v ~/Projects:/Projects ubuntu /bin/bash`
then you're inside that container and can run your binaries

Comment: Just so you understand what is actually happening here. On linux, Docker can use the host operating system's kernel, but on Mac/Windows it can't because Docker is linux dependent. So what actually happens on those platforms is that Docker runs a single linux virtual machine, in which all your Docker containers run.

If you're still having a problem after mounting a directory with the binary in, then post what you tried to do *inside* the docker container.

Comment: @vitr doesn't solve the no such file or directory issue.
I'll update the post with what I tried to do in the container.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with ubuntu) You're just trying to run very specific to radare2 framework binaries

Comment: What is `ch25.bin`? Where does it come from? How was it built? I believe that the error you're seeing has nothing to do with Docker but may be indicative that you're trying to run a binary for the wrong architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mounted shared `Projects` directory with read only, you cannot change the permissions.

You can try either:

- Correct permission on your local file then mount it with the right permissions.
- Try to mount it with write access (`-v ~/Projects:/Projects:rw`) and change the permission from the container (it won't work if you're mounting non-Linux filesystem such as NTFS or FAT32 which won't support Linux file permissions).
- Run non-executable binary directly with a dynamic linker (assuming binary is in ELF format), e.g. for 64bit ELF format:

  ```
    /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ~/Projects/ch25.bin
  ```

  <sup>See: [What is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and why can it be used to execute file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400621/21471)</sup>

  To find the right dynamic linker, you can use this command inside your container:

  ```
  find /lib /usr/lib -name "ld*.so*"
  ```
- If you need 32bit dynamic linker, install `lib32z1` package and use `/usr/lib/ld-linux.so.2` to execute binary.
- Otherwise if your binary file is in different format, use the right parser (for shell script, use `bash ch25.bin`).